# How do I unit test JavaScript event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have jquery code that reacts to a table row click and operates on the data- or class attributes of the row in a function. 
I want to unit test this function (I am using mocha.)
I need to mock the table with rows and attributes. How do I mock this?

```
Table.on("click", "tr", function (event) {
  var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
  // do other stuff
});
```

Comment: I would do this one of two ways: perform the test in a browser (so the element is really being clicked and check the result) -- this can be automated with something like headless Chrome -- or just test the event handler function, without really triggering the event.

Comment: what's the other stuff? that is the important bit..

Comment: @synthet1c  I am wiring up an mvc route using 'data-' field properties so the user can click on a row to navigate from summary through detail views.

Comment: @Sidney I use jsfiddle.

Comment: Unit test for testing small units (functions, methods etc.. in your application), clicking on element is more like behavior test, there are many tools for that example: [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)), [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: As @Peter said, you need to separate your behaviour from your functionality, that's why the rest is important. You will probably need to refactor the rest of the code to be testable.